# Building a Maven Spring Boot project vs building from Intellij?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, build

I'm working on Java projects with Spring Boot and Maven and I'm using Intellij and I want to know if building a a project from Intellij menu: Build -> Build Project is the same thing with building a project with Maven: `mvn clean install`. If not, what is the difference? Thank you[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you build/compile from intellij or eclipse it will just compile the source code whereas **mvn clean install** will build/compile the source and creates the jar file.